# “Die Spinne kümmerte sich um die Hütte.” – Why do we need “sich um”?

Tags: grammar, preposition, reflexive

> Die Spinne kümmerte sich um die Hütte.

means

> The spider took care of the cottage.

But why do we need to add *sich um?* Why not just:

> Die Spinne kümmerte die Hütte.

Comment: Because, uh, it would mean something else? It's like asking, why can't we say, in English, _The spider took care the cottage_, or even _The spider took the cottage_.

Comment: you mean a fixed match?

Comment: What chirlu is trying to tell you is that asking "why isn't it like it is in English" is not a good approach to language learning.

Comment: But why is that?

Comment: Maybe people on this site do not know English well? Why can I not understand what you guys are trying to say?

Comment: The question "why isn't it" followed by an English sentence comes across naive and a bit narrow minded. Why should it be like the English sentence? Instead of asking "why" just ask "what is the function of this and that". That's something we can answer. But "why"... the answer to that is "that's how it is, is all."

Comment: When do I ask why it shouldn't be like as in English? I'm really just asking "what is the function of this and that"

Comment: Also you do not answer my question: is "sich um" a fixed match,

Comment: Well, then just write "what's the function" next time rather than "why". A "why not like [English example]" makes me not want to answer the question. Also:  Where do you ask "is sich um a fixed match"? No, it's not. Verbs come with a preposition and sometimes a reflexive. And sometimes the resulting combination is "sich um"

Comment: Then you must have assumed that I was an ignorant and arrogant American, Lol.

Comment: The verb construction is "sich um jemand/etwas kümmern". Another verb construction is not possible. Why? Because it was accepted in this form by the speaker community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in this case it's *sich kümmern* as *kümmern* is a reflexive verb AFAIK (and I'm not good at grammar but a German speaker).

And to express *care **about** something/somebody* (or more exactly *to take care **of** something/someone*), you need to use *sich **um** etwas/jemanden kümmern*.

In spoken German you could say:

> Wen kümmert's?

or

> Wen kümmert es?

(who cares) but this is the only situation that comes to my mind where *kümmern* is used without the reflexive form.

Some useful links:

- http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-bin/wort_www.exe?site=1&Wort=k%FCmmern
- https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/k%C3%BCmmern

Here you find some reflexive verbs in German:

- http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=33

Comment: Are there any other situations in which you need to add "sich um"?

Comment: @pxc3110... there are plenty and there are thousands with "sich auf" and "sich vor" and so on. The "um" is the same as the English "of" in "take care of".

Comment: What role does "sich" play here? Maybe Germans like to be humurous and add "sich" without any reason?

Comment: @pxc3110: Yes, Germans are world-renouned for their sense of humour.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking for the role of "sich" and you talk about Germans' sense of humor.

Comment: @pxc3110 "sich" just indicates that the verb is reflective. And you might consider this while conjugating "ich kümmere mich, du kümmerst dich, ... wir kümmern uns,..." It's just the same as myself/yourself for example i washed the car and i wash myself the last example is reflexive

Comment: As you already added the reference to Wiktionary, you could link to that at the very beginning while saying "Kümmern is reflexive when it's about taking care of so/sth". – The thing is, currently you're saying that it *is* a reflexive verb and then, though, you give an example where it's not reflexive. So, to make it clear: Add the info that it's reflexive only when it comes to this very meaning. You can drop that "I'm not good at grammar"-part, too. ### On a side note, imho here "sich um etw. kümmern" is more like "to take care of sth". Though, it can be translated as "care about sth", too.

Comment: @Em1 thanks! I adapted it now!

Comment: Wrong preposition ;) You take care **of** someone/something when you care **for** someone/something/yourself OR when you are responsible for something. You care **about** something when you think it's important or you're worried about. – Certainly, the hut is important to the spider, but in this context (although the whole context is not given, so I'm speculating here) the spider is responsible. Thus, "take care **of** something". I'm fixing this now.

Comment: @Em1 must have been stepped away as i never mentioned to use "for"

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

> Die Spinne kümmerte die Hütte.

Here, "die Spinne" would be in the accusative case, "die Hütte" in the nominative case, and it would mean that the hut [troubles](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/k%C3%BCmmern) (or concerns) the spider. This is not the intended meaning.

Since nominative and accusative have identical forms here, it would also be possible that the roles are reversed and the hut is sad about the spider, but that seems even less likely.